# Trouble with push function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am not an experienced programmer, and I have a small amount to knowledge in a few languages, but I started programming in Javascript recently and I ran into an issue with the push function. I wanted to give myself a small project using the skills I had learned in my short time programming with it. This project was to create a program that would "flip" playing cards until it reached the Ace of Spades. I ran into the majority of my problems when I attempted to prevent any repeat cards from being listed. This is the code I have as of now:

```js
var cardNumbers = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','Jack','Queen','King','Ace']
var currentCard = 'Hearts'
var currentCardNumber = '2'
while(currentCard !== 'Spades' || currentCardNumber !== 'Ace') {
  var usedCards = ['Hearts']
  var usedCardNumbers = ['2']
  
  for(var i = 0; i < usedCards.length; i++) {
    for(var t = 0; t < usedCardNumbers.length; t++) {
      if(usedCards[i] === currentCard && usedCardNumbers[t] === currentCardNumber) {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13)
        var randomCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)
        currentCard = cards[randomCard]
        currentCardNumber = cardNumbers[randomNumber]
      } else {
        console.log(currentCardNumber +  ' of '  + currentCard)
      }
    } 
  }
  
  usedCards.push(currentCard);
  usedCardNumbers.push(currentCardNumber)
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13)
  var randomCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)
  currentCard = cards[randomCard]
  currentCardNumber = cardNumbers[randomNumber]
}

console.log('Program has found the Ace of Spades')
```

I believe that I have solved most of the problems because I can now get the code to run, but the push functions at the bottom are now working and it is allowing for repeat cards to be drawn because no cards are being added to the used list. I'm not sure if I'll run into problems after this or if something like this is even possible using only the few things I know so far, but any advice would be helpful

Comment: I meant to say the push functions are not working instead of saying they are now working.

Comment: in this line: currentCard = cards[randomCard]
"cards" doesn't exist, that causes an error

Comment: just like the comment above, you used the same `cards` variable twice, try to press F12 in your browser to open the console and track some errors

Comment: 1) Use indentation. Not only does it help you, it also makes potential answerers not hate you :P 2) When searching for something, you can't use `else` inside the loop to know if you haven't found something; you need to wait till the loop ends to know it's not there. 3) It would be easier to make a deck, then shuffle it, rather than make cards on the spot and look for duplicates. Make a deck of heart A, 2, 3... J, Q, K, spade A, 2, 3.... then shuffle. Look up "array shuffling in JavaScript", plenty of sample code for that.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally left out the first line of code when putting it onto the website. It creates a cards variable that the holds an array of all of the different suits. It still doesn't work when I add that line though and I know the problem is the push function. All of the code runs properly and it reads the push function, but it doesn't add anything to the array it's supposed to add to. In response to Amadan, I would have indented, but I don't know the general rules for doing so. Also, I know that there are better ways for doing this, but I wanted to try it using only what I know so far.